# SQL Server Query check empty fields for a number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to construct a query that returns rows that have certain empty fields.

For example I have 300 records that contain a `Name, Address and City`. Once one or more fields are empty they need to be returned. If I for example have a row that has an empty `City` and a row that has an empty `address`, both need to be returned. What would be the best way to construct this query?

The reason I need this that I would like to construct a dashboard that shows incomplete records so this information can be added.

Comment: And what did you tried so for? Some code?

Comment: When you say empty fields, you mean null values or empty string values ''?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Name IS NULL OR Name = ''
OR City IS NULL OR City = ''
OR [Address] IS NULL OR [Address] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
   ,City
   ,Address
   ,...
FROM TABLE 
WHERE NULLIF(Name,'') IS NULL
OR NULLIF(City,'') IS NULL
OR NULLIF([Address],'') IS NULL
```

Comment: It may look a bit cooler way of writing this simple query but considering sargability not so cool then :)

Answer (score 0):

Well we have the `IS NULL OR` and the `NULLIF`, so I take the `COALESCE`

```
SELECT Name
     , City
     , Address
     , ...
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  COALESCE(Name,'') = ''
   OR  COALESCE(City,'') = ''
   OR  COALESCE([Address],'') = ''
```